# asp:QueryStringParameter and empty query string parameter

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sqldatasource, querystringparameter

I  have`asp:GridView` displaying client requests using `asp:SqlDataSource`. I want to limit displayed information by client:

`View.aspx` has to display everything, `View.aspx?client=1` has to display only requests from client ID #1.

So I'm using `<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="client" QueryStringField="client" />` for query `"EXEC getRequests @client"`.

Everything works properly when some client is specified. But don't - if not.

I tested my SP using SSMS - it works properly in both cases - when parameter is specified and when it isn't (`NULL` passed explicitly).

What have I do?

Comment: Looks like you're opening yourself up to some pretty serious SQL injection attack vectors with this approach.

Comment: @womp: How am I opening? QueryStringParameter is being added in code-behind only for users with appropriate rights and after a number of checks.

Comment: AH, if you're sanitizing it, then that's fine.  It just looked from your question like you were using it directly.

Comment: @womp: I take only client ID (int) and pass it to SP. I'm sure this is safe to do. I don't do silly things like `"SELECT ... WHERE ID=" + Request["client"]` :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SqlDataSource won't fire if any of it's parameters are null, unless you specify otherwise:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" />
```

It might also be necessary to add a null default value to your querystring parameter:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="client" QueryStringField="client" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! First option does what I need.

Comment: That's a a really awkward default (i.e. it should fire with NULL params by default). I'm pretty sure NULL params to indicate 'everything' are very common.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a Default value to the parameter for those situations, for example:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="client" QueryStringField="client" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

and then in the SP you need verify if the client is 0, return all the clients, otherwise the specific one.

Comment: Is it possible to set default value to `NULL` (`DBNull.Value`) ?

Comment: Hmm i dont think so. But is there a reason to use NULL instead of 0, -1 or something else?

Comment: For `NULL` it's easy to use SQL built-in function `ISNULL(,)`. Values like 0 or -1 required additional `CASE-WHEN-THEN` statement into query

Comment: With this url "View.aspx?client=" i think the parameter is automaticly converted to null, because its empty. Try this and give some feedback,

Comment: Thank you for your participation! :) Problem is solved. See below